# how to write a coverpoint to check a signal is on after a particular signal is on?

Tags: system-verilog

Here, I am trying to write a cover point to check after signal a is on, Is there any signal b(on).

```
check: coverpoint {a,b}{
bins hit = {2'b11}
}
```

I believe that the above cover point checks when both signals are on. I am not sure how we exactly write the scenario I mentioned. Any help would be appreciated. And also please help me with the best resources if you know to learn system Verilog.

Answer (score 0):

`cover` directive are much better with temporal sequences than a `covergroup` but that requires a sampling clock:

```
check: cover property (@(posedge clk) a |-> ##[*] b; );
```